# Python name not defined. Linking files

Tags: python, import, hyperlink, enums, constructor

I'm new to python and having trouble linking files and with the constructor.

First, I tried writing pressao.py with an enum and using it on sensor.py, which doesn't work. If I type the pressao.py code into sensor.py, it does work. So the mistake is on the import? Can't find it :(

Regarding the instantiation, it says constructor takes no arguments, but I've defined a constructor and checked spelling. :((

Thanks in advance!

Code for sensor.py below:

```
    from enum import Enum
    import pressao

    # When I uncomment this section below, code works. That's all the code in pressao.py copy-pasted.
    """class Pressao(Enum):
        NORMAL = 0
        BAIXA = 1
        ALTA = 2"""

    class Sensor:
        """Classe responsavel pela definicao dos sensores.
           Atributos:
            int bmp
            bool movimento
            Pressao pressao"""

    def __init__(self, bmp, movimento, pressao):
        self.bmp = int(bmp)
        self.movimento = bool(movimento)
        self.pressao = pressao

    a = Sensor()

    #Says object takes no parameters in python3 and constructor takes no arguments in python 2
    #Third argument should be of type enum Pressao, but I'm testing with string first
    foo = Sensor(100, True, "bar")

    a.bmp = 100
    print(a.bmp)

    #Says Pressao is not defined. However, if I uncomment the code above, it does work.
    a.pressao = Pressao.NORMAL
    print(a.pressao)
```

Comment: Do you by accident have a circular import? (File a imports b and b imports a.)

Comment: No, but on both files I import Enum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You imported file wrong. To use class Pressao, you have to import like following

```
from pressao import Pressao
```

Comment: Thanks! That really did it! ;D (I upvoted but I don't have enough reputation it seems). I thought Import foo would import everything on the file :((

Comment: Do you have any idea on the constructor?

Comment: You already defined constructor, so, you can't instantiate object without parameters

Comment: But the instantiation without parameters is the one that works. When I use with parameters it gives me the error "Constructor takes no arguments"